# Method on how to access a variable?

Tags: java

I'm currently learning Java, and one of the examples in the textbook is as follows:

```
class Circle{
    private double radius;
    private double area;


    public void setRadius(double r){
        radius = r;
        setArea(Math.PI * radius * radius);
    }
    public void setArea(double a){
        area = a;
    }
```

Looking at the setRadius method, is there a style preference/difference between writing what's above VS writing the following?

```
    public void setRadius(double r){
        radius = r;
        setArea(Math.PI*r*r);
    }
```

One of my classmates is making the argument that one should use the parameter `r` instead of the private variable `radius` because a public method shouldn't have direct access to a private variable unless it's by using a getter. Is this more of a style preference or is he right in that public methods directly accessing private methods is bad?

Comment: It depends on requirement...if you see in Circle class there is  <private double radius;> instance variable, they just want to set radius value in that variable as well as wanted to calculate area and again set to instance variable <private double area;>

Comment: In `setArea` you have a **bug**; it should be `this.area = a;` **not** `area = area;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Apologies, that wasn't in the textbook; I just wrote it quickly for this question. I'll change it.

Comment: *because a public method shouldn't have direct access to a private variable* I **disagree**.

Comment: Your classmate is wrong.  Public methods access private fields all the time.

Comment: It depends what is your code requirement, if you want to initialize Circle variable then you should follow this.radius=r and also this.area=a as well also i disagree with your classmate statement.you can access private fields from public methods any time all pojo class is an example for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case both method call are correct

```
setArea(Math.PI * radius * radius);
```

and

```
setArea(Math.PI*r*r);
```

> public method shouldn't have direct access to a private variable unless it's by using a getter

I don't agree for this. because getter also a public method and no meaning of this sentence.

Comment: *getter is also a public method* but have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/1039555) to see why it still is a good practice

Answer (score 4):

That code feels *weird*.  Usually, when you're calling a set method, or a *setter*, you are explicitly setting a value, and nothing else.  The `setArea` method call seems out of place, since that is now a *side effect* of the stated method call, which only specifies `setRadius`.

IMHO, the `area` in the class should be calculated, using the `radius`, once requested, instead of storing both the `radius` and the `area`.  This is how the program should look:

```
class Circle {
    private double radius;

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getArea(){
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

As you see above, the `r vs radius` question goes away completely.

Comment: In as far as the current question goes, I agree with you; however, the class should (arguably) override `Object#equals(Object)`, `hashCode()` and `toString()`. There might also be some value to making the `radius` immutable and using the constructor to set it.